# Clean way to write a very long @query in Springboot

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-annotations

I have a very long sql native query in @query field in JPA repo function. Is there a clean way to write the query, like maybe parse a SQL file and read the query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do that.
First create a sql file with your query and store the file in resources folder.

```
src/main/resources/your_sqlfile.sql
```

In JpaRepository function read the sql file and retrive the query using the classpath object:

below code you can follow:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public List<YourEntity> findByCustomQuery() {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("mycustomquery.sql");
    String query = null;
    try {
        query = Files.readString(resource.getFile().toPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what if we need to insert dynamic variables into the string query. WIth @query we do that via params

Comment: If you need to put dynamic variables  the you can define the placeholder in your query and you can pass your values of variables into it like @Query("select t from Entity E where E.id = ?1")
List<Entity> finById(String id);

Comment: yes but in your answer now you are hardcoding the query in @query, which is not readable for mr

Comment: Its just an example like you can define your query like adding placeholders

Answer (score 0):

You can also use named queries and define the queries in the mapping file.

Comment: yes but in that also the query is still in string. As the query is very long It is not readable

Comment: Since it is a native query, I don't know any other way but a String (or multiple catenated Strings) to define it.